# How to run jar application from window service registry?

Tags: java

**DUPE: [How to create a windows service from java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app)**

I have developed a Java jar application which processes input file and converts into csv file. Now my requirement is to run that jar application fom windows service. I have no idea of how to do that.

How can I make a Java application into a Windows service?