# Create Window Service for java Application

Tags: java, service, window

I have one java application having only one class, which basically do certain things. Right now i need to run manually but actually i want to make it window service so that it run automatically at the back end. I have tried it out with Java Wrapper classes but it didn't work for me
http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/index.html
I have stuck in it
Can any body guide me how to make window service in java though wrapper class or with any other method.

Comment: What did not work for you?

Comment: I am working according to this tutorial but when i run my app it did not start rather it through an error.http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32068          Error "The sendmail service is not install"

Comment: Has _sendmail service_ to do with your application/service?

Comment: Yes basically sendmail service is my java class for which is used to run as window service.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps.

1. Create a jar file from your project.
2. Refer below url to create a service from jar
   [Run JAR as a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114674/run-jar-as-a-windows-service)