# Windows Service can't be started : Cannot start service [name of service] on computer '.'

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, windows-services

I am trying to create windows service with below code

```
$params = @{
  Name = "abc"
  BinaryPathName = "C:\Users\dell\Downloads\abinstall\abc.exe"
  DisplayName = "Windows Service"
  StartupType = "Automatic"
  Description = "This is a service."
}
New-Service @params
```

When i try to run above script i get an output like this

```
Start-Service : Service 'Windows Service (abc)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start
service abc on computer '.'.
At C:\Users\dell\Downloads\abinstall\start.ps1:14 char:4
+    Start-Service -Name "abc"
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

I am running this in administrator powershell.
```

```
PS C:\Users\Public\k2agent-bkp>  Get-CimInstance win32_service | Where-Object Name -eq "abc"

ProcessId Name StartMode State   Status ExitCode
--------- ---- --------- -----   ------ --------
0         abc  Auto      Stopped OK     0
```

I have tried restarting computer after deleting the service.

I am running this on windows 10 workstation.

abc.exe is wrapper over java jar.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617458/how-to-create-windows-service-from-java-jar

Comment: Try to add the credential parameters (`-credential`)