# executing java with another id

Tags: java

I was wondering How to execute java Application with different userName and password.
For example:
Right now: When I do,

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

I get `user1`.

But I want to program in such a way that it says `user2`.

Can somebody help me How to accomplish this with Java or bat files.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you mention bat files I assume you want to do this on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override this value, the same as any other system property with

```
java -Duser.name=my-new-user
```

or

```
System.setProperty("user.name", "my-new-user");
```

Note: neither solution changes the user-id of the process, just the value returned by System.getProperty("user.name");

Answer (score 6):

The java system property `user.name` is set by the operating system. So if you login as a different user and start you're java program, it will run under that username.

But You can also change the user under which you execute an program (if you have sufficient rights for it!).

**Linux**: use the [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) command

```
sudo -u user2 java yourprogram
```

*(but you need to have [sudo rights](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132821), for example by being **root**)*

**Windows** use the [runas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runas) command:

```
runas /user:domain\user2 java yourprogram
```

Comment: could you please tell me where do I give the password for that user.

Comment: @user234194 For Linux or Windows? If you're root in Linux you can do this without a password, the same thing applies when you configure sudo for regular users (see link).

Comment: in windows, i wanna do that in a single line.

Comment: @user234194: Runas will always ask for a password. You could start you're program as a service though.

Comment: could you expalin little bit more please. I am new in this topic. thanks

Comment: @user234194: There are however some scripts on the internet to circumvent this security feature of Runas. For example here (scroll way down): http://www.experts-exchange.com/Operating_Systems/WinXP/Q_20906129.html

Comment: @user234194: You could also take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app

Comment: @user234194: And if it has to start from Batch, why don't you run it under the correct user?

Comment: `psexec` from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) (now part of Microsoft) will allow you to do the equivalent of runas with a username provided as an argument on the command line. It's intended for running code remotely, but works perfectly well for running local stuff too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to user2 (`su user2` on linux), then run your program.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this on Windows, you can use the [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command in a batch file to run in the context of a different user.  On a Unix/Linux system, you can use the [su](http://ss64.com/bash/su.html) command.