# Managing a remote Windows Service

Tags: debugging, logging, service, window

As part of my app, my users install a Window Service (msi file written in C#) that uploads data to me.  These Windows servers are usually behind all kinds of firewalls etc. and run by IT staff so it's difficult to get in touch with anyone to debug.

What can I put inside my application that would make it easier to figure out things?  I'm not looking to do anything that would be considered "shady" but here are some ideas I've thought:

- Open log files that are relevant to me in a separate thread and stream it back up to the server
- Setup some kind of reverse tunnel (not sure if there is a sane shell environment on Windows that I can connect to)

Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, I'm open to completely rewriting this thing in Java and using something from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app (or Ruby if there's anything interesting there)

Answer (score 0):

The author of the logging framework we use (the object guy's) has a [service](http://www.logverse.com) that might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug .NET and native code through remote debugger with Visual Studio, see the post of John Robbins about it : http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2010/06/15/vs-remote-debugging-across-workgroups-or-domains.aspx