# Is it possible to install a headless Eclipse RCP application as a Windows Service?

Tags: java, windows-services, eclipse-rcp

I have a headless Eclipse application that I would like to run as a Windows Service. Is this possible and where could I find more information on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse being a Java App, this previous answer may work for you:
[How to create a windows service from java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app)

Comment: This then raises the question, if Eclipse exports the project already with a .exe launcher/wrapper, why should I wrap it again with another product? The reason for using Eclipse was for the extensibility, and that it already created the application with a Windows executable wrapper. I'm looking to know if Eclipse's exe can be made to work as a service wrapper as well.

Comment: I would do away with the launcher, having Java Service Wrapper directly launch eclipse.  From the eclipse docs: java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.0.v20070606.jar     http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/launcher.html

Comment: Some details from others than have done this... http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg24884.html

Comment: Although this isn't exactly what I was wanting, it seems the only real way of handling this issue. I've talked it over with my team and we have also found a similar route with Yet Another Java Service Wrapper which seems to fit the bill. Thanks for the help.