# Restarting Tomcat service through servlet which is hosted in the same Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, windows-services, servlets

I would like to restart tomcat service on Windows XP, I created a servlet which calls a batch file

```
public void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
 throws ServletException, IOException  {

      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\restart_tomcat.bat");
 }
```

following  2 lines added in my **restart_tomcat.bat**

```
   net stop "Tomcat6" 
   net start "Tomcat6"
```

requesting the servlet URL stops tomcat server however it isn't started.  However when I run batch file restart_tomcat.bat, works fine

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start c:\restart_tomcat.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

The process (e.g. restart_tomcat.bat) that is launched by the JVM is likely being killed too when the VM exits so `net start` never executes. Tomcat uses [Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/) which, unfortunately, does not support JVM restarting. (Or  I don't how to do it.)

A quick hack: set the service recovery mode to automatically restart.

Longer-term, there are lots of other [JVM as a Service options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app) some of which support self-restarting.