# How to run Java application at system startup on Windows/Linux/MacOS?

Tags: java, cross-platform, java-native-interface, startup, jna

How I can run Java application at system startup on Windows/Linux/MacOS?

Any implementation of JNA/JNI shall be welcome.

Comment: Isn't there any JNA/JNI implementation that actually works

Comment: JNA/JNI are not technologies to start processes at startup, they are used to call native code from a Java application.

Comment: Yeah I know that but there are common libraries to access to similar functionality under different OSes... this is my first project in java I would like to learn if there are some.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a windows service from java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app)

Comment: @Vadzim Given the scope of that question is about windows services, which restricts it to Windows, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, yes, but that question is more mature and many solutions there are multiplatform and applicable here too.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org. It provides a wrapper for java applications to run under the various operating systems. You can use the community edition.

Comment: Downloadable TanukiSoftware Java Service Wrapper 64-bit binaries for Windows: http://www.krenger.ch/blog/tag/java-service-wrapper/

Answer (score 3):

You can consider your application as a service under linux, and add a script that could start it under /etc/init.d (on most distributions, I think). You'll then have to make the needed links to the runlevel folders, to decide when to run your application. I think you can use [chkconfig](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_chkconfig.htm) too

A basic example of script can be found [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/newbie/97097-how-create-linux-service-daemon.html)

I don't have most clues for the other two systems, however.

Answer (score 3):

On windows you can use reg add 
Add the path of your application to hklm/software/microsoft/windows/current version/run
To see more ,on command prompt type reg add /?
Alternatively yo can use system call to add it from your application itself

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/. 
It's free and compatible reimplementation of TanukiSoftware Java Service Wrapper featuring free 64-bit support.

There is also a comparison table for [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/), [JSW](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/), [ACD](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/) and [L4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).