# Run a Java standalone application on Windows (as a service)

Tags: java, windows, amazon-ec2

I have a standalone Java application which will run continuously post start-up (e.g. `java com.<mycompany>.FooServer`) on a Windows EC2 instance.

Currently I have started this from a command shell. How do I make sure that it runs on a re-boot, should I be wrapping this into a Windows service? What is the easiest way to handle start/stop of my standalone server?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app - Is this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

Create a `.bat` file to hold your Java command and create a Windows service using

`sc create FooServerService binPath= C:\path\to\start.bat start= auto DisplayName= "My Foo Service"`

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, `sc` requires them. I have tested the above command.