# Automatically running a Java application at OS startup

Tags: java, startup

I need some way of starting my Java application without forcing the user to run the application manually. I'm not entirely sure how I would do it, can anyone provide any assistance?

Comment: Assigning it to what?

Comment: Believe he wants to programmatically assign a program to run on start-up.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think he means manually assigning it to run at startup. Ending sentences with prepositions.

Comment: Assigning in the other sense. Should be read "running a java application at startup without manually clicking it to run it or scheduling a task for startup." He wants code to automatically run his program

Comment: I don't think there's a platform-independent way to do this, what operating system or systems do you need this for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Java application at Windows startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953525/run-java-application-at-windows-startup)

Answer (score 2):

**Run it as a Windows Service.**  It's the way to go.

For various ways to run it as a service, check out the answers to the following questions:

- **[Install java program as a windows service: Alternative to JavaService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262040/install-java-program-as-a-windows-service-alternative-to-javaservice)**
- **[How to create a windows service from java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app)**

You can also read [**this article.**](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/34438)

Answer (score 1):

use registry editor to add path of .exe file to startup goto Run from start menu, type regedit.exe

then navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER / SOFTWARE / MICROSOFT / WINDOWS / CURRENT_VERSION / RUN

on the right side, create a new string value with

name = "anything" and
value = java.exe -jar "complete path of the file"

press ok to save the registry entry, restart your pc to see effect