# A background app to send email

Tags: java

I need to develop a small app in Java (Windows Platform) which should remain in memory all the time and access a mysql database. If a row is inserted to a particular table with a particular status, I should be able to generate an email and forward it to a particular person.

I know the how to access a mysql database, check for the row status and generating email etc. But how to write a background process to listen for the interesting row and what tools can be used to accomplish this job is what I would like to know. Please shed some light.

Thank you.

Sudheer

Comment: If I understand correctly, the question is not about "a background app to send email", but rather "how to monitor a msql database for changes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows term for an application that automatically runs in the background is a "service". There are several ways to make a Java application into a service, see this question: [How to create a windows service from java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

1. Background app:
   A loop with a sleep inside it.
   After each sleep, check the database table.
2. Sending email:
   Google JavaMail