# Make Quartz Scheduler as Service

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have implemented a Quartz Job scheduler to call one java process for every 30 sec which is working fine.To start the scheduler ,what i am doing is , create bat file contains java - jar "MainJava.jar".Once we click the jobScheduler.bat file ,job is started but the problem is if any one close window,job is stoped.So to avoid this kind of issue ,is there any option to start and stop the quartz scheduler using command prompt for Eg:

if i say  "start jobScheduler from command line" job has to start.Job has to stop only while issuing the stop jobScheduler from command prompt"

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113

Comment: You can try java service wrapper at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wrapper/

Comment: Please share your solution. I also need it