# Java App like window Service

Tags: java, windows-services

I want to run my Java app like a Windows service. It should not close when I logoff from windows and it should be started automatically on windows boot. I used the JSmooth wrapper for that. It's now starting the Java app on Windows boot.

But the problem is when I logoff from Windows it is closing my application. I really don’t want to close my Java Application on Windows logoff.

Please suggest me the best possible solutions or some other wrapper which can perform that task.

Thanks

Comment: Are you starting it as a windows service? If you start it when you login it will stop when you log off.

Comment: I think that this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app) may cover the same topic

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by checking out [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html).