# Publish stand alone java web service

Tags: java

I created a stand alone java web service. I am able to publish it from command line(using java command). The problem is the service stops running when I close the command window. How can I have this service always running. One suggestion was to execute publish-service from build.xml. Could anyone please tell me how to modify the build.xml to publish the service and have it up and running.

Comment: running a java application as a background service is a platform specific task, what operating system?

Comment: Following Link may already provide a solution for your problem: [how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app

Comment: And can't this be accoplished without the wrapper?