# How to monitor folders using a service

Tags: java, filesystemwatcher

I wrote a program that can monitor the folders and let me know changes in those folders. 
But this should run whole the day until the system is ON. This should run as a task in background(like batch process).
I am using Java WatchService  for monitoring the folders.
I need some suggestions,

1. How can make this as a service that run in background as a batch
   process?
2. If i make this as service, will this effect the performance of the
   system? as there will be files added for every 5mins atleast in the
   folders.

Please suggest your ideas.

Thanks

Comment: You describe the service as a batch process, so I guess you're looking for a Windows solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can and it should not effect your system performance when your system have enough resource.

**Steps to do that in java**

1. Write a small java class `FolderMonitor` to monitor a particular folder.

   1. Load a Directory `File("C:\folder1")`
   2. Iterate all the file and hold its last modified time in a `Map`
      map key can be a foderName+fileName and value is modified time.
   3. Check with last iteration value, if found modified or new file added do process what you need.
   4. Run the above thru `ScheduledExecutorService` with required interval
2. Make `FolderMonitor` class into a jar.

**Make it service**

1. You can use `apache's procrun` or `tanukisoftware` service wrapper for creating a service from java executable jar

   1. Links [Java Service wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) & [Apache Procrun](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html)

Hope you can do it. All the best

Answer (score 3):

Q> How can make this as a service that run in background as a batch process?
A> See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app) SO post, it addresses the same question.

Q> If i make this as service, will this effect the performance of the system? as there will be files added for every 5mins atleast in the folders.
A> Because you are using `WatchService`, this should be really cheap. Quoting [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html):

> Most file system implementations have native support for file change
>   notification. The Watch Service API takes advantage of this support
>   where available. However, when a file system does not support this 
>   mechanism, the Watch Service will poll the file system, waiting for events.

If in doubt, you can always monitor your server and see how much CPU and I/O your app uses. I bet this won't be a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make a thread with an infinite loop, like

```
while(true) {
   //code and logic
   Thread.sleep(theTimeYouWantBetweenTheScans);
}
```

Create a .bat file for convinience with stuff, like java -jar myMonitor.jar

The performance depends on your code, but it shouldn't be very heavy. Enjoy.