# JavaService.exe on windows server 2012

Tags: java, windows, windows-services, windows-server-2012, java-service-wrapper

I'm trying to run a Java application as Windows service using JavaService.exe (http://forge.ow2.org/projects/javaservice)  On Windows Server 2012.

I'm getting a generic error and the service does not start. In the event viewer I get the following:

> The description for Event ID 4097 from source 'XXX" cannot be found.
>   Either the component
>       that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is 
>       corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

Any Idea how to ran java as windows service in windows server 2012

Comment: Please, could you open more information about JavaService.exe? Or try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app

Comment: http://forge.ow2.org/projects/javaservice

Comment: Are you shure, that this JavaService.exe should working on windows 2012 (requirements from site - Operating System: Windows NT/2000)? From my perspective, http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html is more usefull and working fine with production systems such as CruiseControl CI build server and so on.

Comment: it work fine on windows server 2008 X64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by copying the msvcr100.dll file from the bin/ directory of Java 7 into the same directory as the java service executable