# How to create a windows service with launch4j?

Tags: java, launch4j

I am creating and executable of a java app with launch4j. How can i configure it to be loaded as a windows service?

With [Jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) i can set the wrapper but i dont know if this can be done in launch4j

Comment: Maybe http://commons.apache.org/daemon/index.html can help?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app?

Answer (score 0):

In this comparison it looks like "Run as Windows Service" can't be done with launch4j:
http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/#mozTocId284533

You can do it with other programs like: Java Service Wrapper, Apache Commons Daemon...

Answer (score 0):

Java JAR executable can be converted to the exe file (for instance, with [launch4j](https://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)). Exe file can be launched as a windows service

```
sc create “My new service” bin path= “D:\FinalProduct\finalProduct.exe” start= auto
```

[Additional](https://medium.com/@parkavi113/java-program-as-windows-service-ea2a90ee4d5f) [information](https://techblog.bozho.net/installing-java-application-as-a-windows-service/)