# Install java program as a windows service through command prompt

Tags: java, windows, service

> Hi I was able to create a Service but now when i am trying to run it comes up with error code : 4 System cannot open the file specified

```
Error code:4
```

Comment: did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app

Comment: I was able to fix it i made a mistake in providing classpath..  Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any opensource apis/tool then you can always create a batch file (in windows), which will run the program and then create a windows service which will call the batch file. While do so make sure all the paths are proper, and if any clsspath is having relative references, you have to format it in such a way that the batch job can run from any location in the computer (better not to use any relative path and put the base path in environment variable and use the variable). Hope this will help.