# Java Service class thatis similar to C#'s ServiceBase

Tags: c#, java, windows, service

I am currently working on a project where I need to create and abstract class in java that inherits the same methods as the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase in C#.

Specifically I am attempting to create a class in Java that is based off a class that I was given in C#. The class I was given looks as follows.

```
///// This is C# code
public abstract class SQSService : ServiceBase
{
    ....

private void ReceiveTask(){....}
private void DeleteTask(){....}
private void WindowCallback(){....}
private void StartProcesses(){....}
private void StopProcesses(){.....}
private void OnNewWindow(){....}
private void Service_NewWindow(){.....}

helperfunctions.......
}
```

Can someone please suggest what would be the best way to go about recreating this in Java, or at least suggesting a class I can extend to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ServiceBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used when you want to turn your executable into a [Windows Service.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service)

Creating a Windows Service in Java is not so straightforward. You can take a look here: [How to create a windows service from java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app)