# Running java application as a windows service

Tags: java, windows, service, startup

I would like to run my java application as a windows service. All I need is some sort of startup script (similar to init.d in linux). I cannot afford the luxury of any paid libraries. I would like to keep it independent of any third party libraries if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app

Comment: I don't believe there is any solution that is independent of 3rd party libraries / utilities.

Comment: I had the same problem years ago.  I found a free support utility that was part of Project Kenai that would do that.  Not sure if it's still available, but try googling around...

Answer (score 0):

Consider Apache Commons Daemon project:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/

Answer (score 0):

May be you just should register a task for Windows Task Scheduler, that just runs java.exe with required parameters, and set trigger for this task "powered on", "system started" or such.