# Have Jar copy to another Directory when Executed

Tags: java, jar, copy, startup, execute

I have a Jar file that when I'm executing I would essentially like it to copy to windows startup, and start on its own.

If this isn't a possibility I'd like to copy the JAR file to another directory and then modify the registry to have it start this file on startup.

I've tried using Files.Copy and using FileStreams without any success for the currently running file, is this going to require me placing the Executable Jar within a jar to essentially copy the file, and then execute it?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question. It seems like you want your program to run on startup.
If that is correct, then you could have your java class run as a windows service. Try using a java service wrapper like tanuki software.

[Running java application as a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321672/running-java-application-as-a-windows-service)
[How to create a windows service from java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app)