# how to send Automatic notification on users machine's as pop up's on some particular event?

Tags: java, push-notification, jms

I have a requirement in which if i am shutting down a server then a notification goes to interested user which bring a pop up on user machine so that they can immediately take any action on this.

It may be like if i am shutting down server than I create an event or message and now according to this event a pop up should come on interested users machine.

Do i need to run a client program in each user machine which will listen that message and will bring that message as pop up on user machine.

I need some ideas that how we can implement this thing in java. It should be something like a window service is running on user machine and if it receives any notification it bring a pop up on user machine and block user to work on mahcine untill he respond to that pop up.

Some one said to me that facebook developer have this type of service. Automatic pop-up for priority communications will help users to take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd need some sort of client running on each machine.

For creating Java applications that run as Windows services, [How to create a windows service from java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app) is informative.

JMS would be useful to accomplish this.  On your server you can create a JMS Topic (this will use the Publish-Subscribe model) and then have each of the clients register interest in that topic.  Each client will then be notified of messages when they are published to that topic and can take whatever action is necessary.

Comment: is java service wrapper free? I need a free way by which i can efficiently run my java as window applications on my machine as long as  after once installed on my machine.