# how to convert an executable java jar file to an window service

Tags: java

I have created a jar file in java , the problem is when ever the system gets restart i need to manually run the jar file so i have decided to convert my jar file to a windows service . if anyone knows please help me out

Comment: Pick one there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app

Answer (score 0):

The **[Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html)** makes it possible to install a `Java Application` as a `Windows Service`. Likewise, the scripts shipped with the `Wrapper` also make it very easy to install a `Java Applicatio`n as a `Daemon` process on `UNIX` systems.

The `Wrapper` correctly handles "**user's log outs**" under `Windows`, service dependencies, and the ability to run services which interact with the desktop.

Take a look at this

[**Java Service Wrapper**](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html)