# Run a java program in a remote computer (LAN) from android device

Tags: java, sockets, server, client-server

I ve built an android application that shares files from mobile to pc over wifi. To initiate the sharing, i need to run socket programming server code in my pc.

Is there any way to run the server code remotely through my android device?

Comment: A server written in java listening to a socket can be wrapped as operating system service, and hence automatically running.

Comment: So it basically runs the whole time. Is there any other way around? Like we send a request packet to the pc and the os starts the process?

Comment: Something similar to wake-on-lan feature?

Comment: The running loop will consist of a server socket _wait_, hence not costing CPU when idle. For Windows I do not know of any easy services though there might be. For a running Linux, one could make a remove shell connection. Maybe e-mail?

Comment: Is there any way similar to wake-on-lan feature? If not then, how to notify the server program while its in wait state?

Comment: `ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber); Socket s = serverSocket.accept();` will wait till communication happens on that port. The operating system will accept communication on that port (firewall!) and trigger the application listening/waiting on that port.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it! And is there any other way?

Comment: It is not wifi. E-mails seem to me the easiest. Or storing them in the sky and then periodically fetching them on the server. More productive.

Comment: Have you heard of Wake-on-LAN feature? Like we can send a network message to turn on a computer? Is there any such way? Thanks anyways!

Comment: There is, but having no experience...

Comment: Can i make my program a Window System service without installing third party applications such as Java Wrapper Application?

Comment: Java 8's javapackager seems to be usable, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app

Comment: I ve no experience with javapackager.. so can you elaborate a bit? I mean, how to add javapackager to my code and how to make that code a window service?

Comment: Sorry javapackager is new for me too.

Comment: Can you say, what a javapackager is? I ve googled.. but couldn't understand a bit..

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/selfContainedApps/index.html explains it and gives a hands-on tutorial. The earlier link for usage as a service.

Comment: Suppose i ve developed an application using javapackager and generated .exe file. Now, if i share the application to other pc, does the program run as a Window service in that pc too?