# How to run a java application in windows like,how antivirus runs always

Tags: java

I have a run able jar of My own java application,but I want to make that application run in windows background process always instead of clicking every time to run it.How to do that?

Comment: There are some good suggestions on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a windows service from java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is use frame with minimum size and run everything there, pretty sure it's not the best method but it does the trick.