# Not able to run the jar file as window service

Tags: java, windows, service

I have created one `.jar` file and am able to execute the `.jar` from a `.bat` file. Please find my `TestBatFile.bat`.

```
@ECHO OFF
start java -jar C:\Users\Karthikeyan\Desktop\TestingJar.jar
```

Then i created windows service to execute this file using the below command.

`C:\Windows\system32>sc create "testservice" start= demand displayname= "MyService" binpath= C:\Users\Karthikeyan\Desktop\TestBatFile.bat`

Service has been created successfully. But while am starting the service am getting the below error.

```
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Please find my below java file which i made as `.jar` file.

```
public class TestJarClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Service Started....");
    }
}
```

Comment: add something like `time /t >> C:\temp\serv.log` to the head of your .BAT and then check if the time is being written to that log file

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger - time is writting in the `serv.log` if i ran the `.bat` file manually. If i try to start as a service then, its not writting.

Comment: than this is not a java problem/question, more like how to create a windows service.... I believe that a BAT cannot be run as a service, somehow you must create a service *program* that has a defined interface (C, C++, C#). I believe that there are some *wrappers* that can be registered as service and which call java programs, must search the internet or https://stackoverflow.com/q/68113/85421