# Windows - running command as a service

Tags: java, windows, service

I have a command that I would like to create a service from. For example: "java -jar agent.jar" (the command is blocking - when closing the cmd it will stop the agent). I would like to make the command run as a service in the background so I can log out from my user and it will still work.
On Linux, I know for a fact that I can use `nohup mycommand`. The problem is on **Windows** OS. Also, replace `java` with `javaw` will solve the blocking issue but when I sign out it will still kill the agent.
How do I do that?
I'll appreciate your help!

Tomer.

Comment: In certain cases - such as for per-user background tasks - you can set up a new task under Computer Management / Task Scheduler which may avoids adding as a Windows Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Windows services feature.

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app).
And this [solution](https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunJavaApplicationAsAService.html).