# how to create a window service using java?

Tags: java, service, ldap, window, onpremises-gateway

is it possible to run a java program as window service is anyone done that successfully ,?

I'm trying to create LDAP application using java, want to run a java application as a window service, java is good choice or not, if any of you guys done any simple window service using java means ,can you please share the steps, thanks!

Comment: _"java is good choice or not"_ - that's opinionated. Personally, I'd say there are better but also much worse. So, if you already _know_ Java, you're good to go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a windows service from java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are a number of frameworks available. I would recommend [commons-daemon](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html), which I have been using for a long time. It is well documented, so just follow the instructions to get it up and running.