# Ruby script as service

Tags: ruby, linux, cron

Well, the title say it all. I have a ruby script I want running as a service (one I can start and stop) on my Linux box. I was able to find how to do it on Windows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163497/running-a-ruby-program-as-a-windows-service)

Some readings point to creating daemons or cron tasks.

I just need something simple I can call on my box's reboot, and can stop/start whenever I please. my script has an internal sleep call, and runs in "eternal loop"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've actually found a much better way of doing that by using ruby scripts.

This is how I did it:

First of all, I installed daemon

```
gem install daemons
```

Then I did:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

pwd  = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
file = pwd + '/runner.rb'

Daemons.run_proc(
   'my_project', # name of daemon
   :log_output => true
 ) do
   exec "ruby #{file}"
end
```

I then create a file called runner.rb, in which I can call my scripts such as:

```
require "/var/www/rails/my_project/config/environment"
Post.send('details....')
```

Daemons is a great gem!

Comment: Better to use: "gem install daemons" the singular one is different. You probably want http://rubygems.org/gems/daemons

Comment: this is a "non linux" way of doing things - albeit one that clearly works. I would propose that using base linux features (e.g. systemd) is also useful in that it's more general, applicable to non-ruby scenarios and makes for some learning about basic linux features.

Answer (score 7):

Posting my answer after more than a decade Original Poster asked the question.

First, let's create a simple ruby script, which will run an infinite loop:

```
# mydaemon.rb 
$stdout.reopen('/home/rmishra/mydaemon.log', 'a')
$stdout.sync = true
loop.with_index do |_, i|
  puts i
  sleep(3)
end
```

You can run the script in the background by appending ampersand:

```
/home/rmishra$ ruby mydaemon.rb &
[1] *pid*
```

To start this script automatically and restart it whenever it was stopped or crashed, we will create a service.

```
# mydaemon.service
[Unit]
Description=Simple supervisor

[Service]
User=username
Group=username
WorkingDirectory=/home/username
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ruby mydaemon.rb

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now, let's copy this service file to systemd directory:

```
sudo cp mydaemon.service /lib/systemd/system -v
```

Finally, use the `enable` command to ensure that the service starts whenever the system boots:

```
sudo systemctl enable mydaemon.service
```

The service can be started, stopped or restarted using standard `systemd` commands:

```
sudo systemctl status mydaemon
sudo systemctl start mydaemon
sudo systemctl stop mydaemon
sudo systemctl restart mydaemon
```

[Source](http://rustamagasanov.com/blog/2017/02/25/systemd-example-for-a-simple-ruby-daemon-supervision/)

Comment: This is the correct answer for any Linux distribution that's using systemd.

Answer (score 3):

[RAA - deamons](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/daemons/) is a verfy useful tool for creating unix daemons from ruby scripts.

Comment: That seems rather complicate. Could you post an example of usage? Or anything simpler?

Comment: Daemons aren't simple. There are a lot of assumptions about capabilities that the OS expects from a daemon... creating and defining those capabilities are a significant part of the complexity of Daemons.

Answer (score 0):

From 1.9.x ruby has a built in function:

`Process.daemon`