# Error while runnnig whenever --update-crontab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, scheduler

I am new to cron job. I am getting the following error while running the whenever --update-crontab.

```
C:\RailsProject>whenever --update-crontab
The system cannot find the path specified.
running cron_job scheduler at Tue Aug 13 14:16:09 +0530 2013
[fail] Couldn't write crontab; try running `whenever' with no options to ensure your schedule file is valid.
```

Any one please help me on this.

Thnks in Advanced.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, the `whenever` gem only runs on *nix systems (Linux, Mac OSX, BSD, ...) and not on windows.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6784889/1065703 for alternatives on windows systems.