# The system cannot find the path specified, whenever gem

Tags: ruby

I want to use whenever gem to run a method every one minute. The problem is that when i try to update it (whenever -i) i get this error

```
The system cannot find the path specified. C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/whenever-0.9.4/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:72:
in 'popen': No such file or directory - crontab - (Errno::ENOENT)   
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/whenever-0.9.4/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:72:in 'write_crontab'   
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/whenever-0.9.4/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:35:in 'run'   
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/whenever-0.9.4/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:6:in 'execute'   
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/whenever-0.9.4/bin/whenever:41:in '<top (required)>'   
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/whenever:23:in 'load'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/whenever:23:in '<main>'
```

Could someone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the directory paths showing in your error output it appears that you are running on Windows. The problem is that the whenever gem is a wrapper for the unix/linux command 'cron' which doesn't exist on Windows. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784149/how-to-make-whenever-gem-work-on-windows) for more details.